# Creating multiple new rows in a dataframe based on existing data

Tags: r, row

Suppose I have the following dataset:

```
data.frame(country = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C"),
           type = c("x", "z", "x", "z", "x", "z"),
           value = c(4, 2, 6, 10, 54, 10))
```

```
  country type value
1       A    x     4
2       A    z     2
3       B    x     6
4       B    z    10
5       C    x    54
6       C    z    10
```

What I want to do is to create multiple new rows for each country (A, B, C) with a new  type called "z-x" and a new value which is the difference between the values z and x. I'm looking for this output:

```
data.frame(country = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C"),
           type = c("x", "z", "z-x", "x", "z", "z-x", "x", "z", "z-x"),
           value = c(4, 2, -2, 6, 10, 4, 54, 10, -44))
```

```
  country type value
1       A    x     4
2       A    z     2
3       A  z-x    -2
4       B    x     6
5       B    z    10
6       B  z-x     4
7       C    x    54
8       C    z    10
9       C  z-x   -44
```

Answer (score 6):

This assumes your data is already sorted so that (within each country) `x` comes before `z`.

```
df |>
  summarize(type = "z - x",
            value = diff(value),
            .by = country) |>
  bind_rows(df) |>
  arrange(country, type)
#   country  type value
# 1       A     x     4
# 2       A     z     2
# 3       A z - x    -2
# 4       B     x     6
# 5       B     z    10
# 6       B z - x     4
# 7       C     x    54
# 8       C     z    10
# 9       C z - x   -44
```

If you'd prefer to be more explicit, this does the trick:

```
df |>
  summarize(
    value = value[type == "z"] - value[type == "x"],
    type = "z - x",
    .by = country) |>
  bind_rows(df) |>
  arrange(country, type)
```

Comment: It worked for the hypothetical example, but it did not work in my database. My database has other columns and they all get NAs after running the code.

Comment: @PedroCardoso - `NA` would be a (maybe the only) reasonable value to provide for other columns imho. You're creating a new record based only on `country` and `value` so those are the only columns that get filled. If the other columns are constant within each `country` group you could potentially add them to the `.by=` as well, but if they're not constant then you'd have to have some logic for creating the new values.

Comment: Whoops, "based on `country`, `value` *and* `type`" I mean.

Comment: In that case @PedroCardoso I'd suggest creating a new question with example data that includes 1 or 2 other columns along with what value you'd want for them in the result. As thelatemail says, from your description I can't imagine any values other than `NA` being appropriate. But in a new question you could show and explain what you want.